# The most simple plugin for file uploading (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there are any simple plugin like paperclip or attachment_fu without any special image stuff? I want something like

```
class Attachment < CoolPlugin::File
  belongs_to :post
end
```

And then do

```
@post.attachments.create(params[:attachment])
```

in my controller.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Just use paperclip. By default it won't use the image processing unless you give it a `:styles` hash.

Answer (score 1):

Try CarrierWave

- https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave
- http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it but a friend told me CarrierWave is better if you want to make an entire model to represent the attachment instead of saying that an attachment is part of another model.